# Filtering out file contents in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a data file and need to differentiate between letters and numbers. This is a sample of that file.

```
Fahrenheit degrees: 67.2
Fahrenheit degrees: 66.0
Fahrenheit degrees: 78.9
Fahrenheit degrees: 102.1
Fahrenheit degrees: 32.0
Fahrenheit degrees: 87.8
```

The end goal is to read each of these numbers, convert it to Celcius, and then print out the results. What function would I use to go down line by line and read just the numbers? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure where to start. I'm new to python. I've been able to read a single line (f.readline()) and also been able to read all the lines (f.readlines()). Beyond that not much.

Comment: So, 1) you read the file line by line, 2) extract numbers 3) convert them from F to C, then 4) print the results. Which phase are you in?

Comment: read the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Then consider checking out the link @PadraicCunningham left above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    numbers = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in f]
```

You use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) context manager to open your file containing your data, then iterate over each line in the file, splitting on whitespace, and taking the third (indexes in Python are 0-based) field and casting it to a float. At the end, you'll have a list of all your readings.

`with` handles closing the file when you're done with it, so you don't need to remember to match each `f = open("filename.txt")` with a call to `f.close()` later on.

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: @DeeWBee yes, use `int` instead of `float`